# Reading response from async/await pattern in try/catch block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, try-catch

I'm making an API request using the async/await pattern in a try/catch block..

```
async myRequest(data) {

  try {

    await api.post('/my-endpoint/', data).then((response) => { 

        console.log(response.data)
    });

  } catch (ex) {

     // WANT TO READ RESPONSE DATA HERE
  }
}
```

If the request succeeds without errors, I am able to read the `response` with the `.then()` method.

If the request fails, this API returns a `422` code that triggers the try/catch exception.

However, if the request fails, this API still returns some data in the response body that I would like to to read but unable to because `catch` is triggered and `.then()` is never run.

How can I get the response body from the async function within the `catch` block?

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you are on Axios lib:

```
catch (e) {
  console.log(e.response.data);
}
```

console.log uses the toString method to format Error objects so it is hard to find the response property if you only log e (error).
Docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Answer (score 0):

The error object is stored in `ex` so you can log the error with
`} catch (ex) { console.log(ex) }`
One of the problems you are making is putting the `.then` after you call your API. When you are using the try-catch block you don't need to do the then because you can save the result into a variable.

One of the benefits of the try-catch block is that the errors are handled and you can do multiple async calls

```
async myRequest(data) {

  try {

    const response = await api.post('/my-endpoint/', data)
    console.log(response.data)
  } catch (ex) {

     console.log(ex)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the response data from a catch block, you can do it technically.

See the following code.

```js
const myRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/xxx/1').then((result)=> {
     

       // You can change the status code to 422 
       if (result.status === 404) {
         throw new Error('You can put your data here.')
         // Make sure the argument you passed in Error is a string 
       }

      return result.json()
    })
      
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
}

myRequest()
```